# Vim: colon appends .,.+3

Tags: vim, iterm2

Sometimes when entering `:`, vim appends `.,.+3` to it, preventing me from executing a command. I couldn't find anything about this behaviour online, is there a way to get do away with it? At the moment, I use vim 8.0 (in iTerm2) but it also used to occur in earlier versions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens when you typed a number before the colon. Vim interprets it as the number of lines on which you want your ex command to operate.

If you press `4:` you get `:.,.+3` which is a range that covers the current line (`.`) and the three lines below the current line (`.+3`).

That behavior is old and documented in `:help N:` (`:help :range` is an interesting read, too).

If you want to get rid of that range, see `:help <C-u>`.